# How do I format (bold) totals without decimal places, in a Word table?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, table-styles

I'm trying to have a table containing currency amounts, without decimal places.

I want a bold totals row, using the native "Totals Row" option for tables, and I would of course like it to keep its formatting when the formula updates.

Here's my initial table, note the checkboxes at the top left, and the selected design (which gives the double lines and bold for the last row):
[image]
I'm inserting my 'Total' formula using the Layout > Formula ribbon button:

[image]

(note the number format to get rid of decimal places)

When done, I want:
[image]

The piece I'm stuck on is that the total ends up looking like this after I select it and press F9 to update the total, no matter how I manually format it, turn the 'Totals' checkbox off and on, etc:

[image]

How do I get the total to stay bold, even after formula refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think your result should take on the formatting of the text in the cell, i.e. it should be bold. I think this is an error, and you could report it to Microsoft, e.g. using their "Smiley" mechanism. But that won't solve the problem until they decide to solve it, so...
2. ...what fixed it here was to

a. use Alt-F9 to show the field code for the sum. Given the formatting option you applied, that is probably

```
{ =SUM(ABOVE) \#0 }
```

b. click after the "0" and type *Charformat, so you have

```
{ =SUM(ABOVE) \#0 \*Charformat }
```

c. select the field code and press F9 to update it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you came across is one of the peculiar problem that we experience while working on Word for calculation and interpretation of data. However, it seems impossible to get the value in the total column properly, with text formatted in the way that we want.

I have experienced the same issue several times, and by now, I have an effective workaround to solve the same.

So, you have got everything working and you need to get that total amount in bold, right? But, Microsoft Word doesn't allow for it for some unknown reasons.

No problem. Here we are going to force Microsoft Word to use the bold type of characters. For this purpose, just select the amount and change the font style to ***Franklin Gothic Demi Cond***. I have chosen this particular type of font, because it matches the *Calibri* font used in the whole document to the closest. Moreover, this font is pre-formatted to be used in bold form. When you do this setting and change the values of the columns and press F9 to refresh the data in the total amount column, you are going to get the amount in Bold form, just like this:

[image]

Here you go. You have the total amount staying bold even after refreshing the formula.

If you want to experiment with bold fonts other than ***Franklin Gothic Demi Cond*** to match up with your whole document, you are free to do so. But, this is how the issue needs to be addressed until Microsoft allows us to get the **$Amount** in bold.

Comment: Sorry, this is an interesting approach but I don't like the idea of trying to visually match up fonts like that - what if I decide to change my Normal font to be based on something else (which I have)?